# c++ Вывести переменную как значение в enum

Tags: c++, enum

есть такой код:

```
namespace Eve {
    enum Num : int
    {
        A = 0x0,
        B = 0x2,
        C = 0x4,
        D = 0x6,
        E = 0x8,
        ...
    }
};
int event = 2;
```

я могу сравнить **event == B**, но мне нужно вывести **event** в *std::cout* как **B**

Есть какой-то простой вариант?

Comment: [magic_enum](https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum)

Comment: `const char* names[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"/*,...*/}; std::cout << names[event>>1];`.

Comment: ...или через что-то типа `map`.